# Accidently deleted current working directory in sftp. How to recover?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I wanted to delete a directory in my sFTP server but I accidently deleted current directory using:

```
rmdir .
```

now any operation on the sever is getting me the error:

```
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
```

How can I recover from this mistake. The only command that is working is `pwd` which is telling me that I'm in `/` which I was at before and it should be deleted now. I don't have permission to go on parent directories and I also tried reconnecting to maybe "reset" the working directory but it didn't work. I'm accessing the server using the built-in command `sftp` in windows.

Comment: rmdir removes (deletes) directories, and '.' is your current directory.
In this case, I assume your directory was empty.

Comment: Ask to restore from backup or snapshot.